# Confluent Kafka Python Error: Metadata request failed

Tags: python, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform, confluent-kafka-python

Getting below error. Not Sure whats wrong.

```
%5|1591739081.630|REQTMOUT|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator/290: Timed out HeartbeatRequest in flight (after 10622ms, timeout #0)
%4|1591739081.630|REQTMOUT|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator/290: Timed out 1 in-flight, 0 retry-queued, 0 out-queue, 0 partially-sent requests
%4|1591739094.726|METADATA|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: GroupCoordinator/289: Metadata request failed: partition assignor: Local: Broker node update (-336618544ms): Permanent
```

Comment: Hi @Hardik, could you please paste your code inside your question? This will make it easier for the community to help you. You can also follow the guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @toshiro92 this is more then enough to answer the question, consider that this is the only thing that kafka let you see when you get this error

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know this error comes from timingout from the brokers.

It based on the `session.timeout.ms` of the consumer, the default value is `10000` which mean that if the consumer cannot complete a heartbeat within 10 seconds he will be kickedout.

consumer try to send heartbeat every `heartbeat.interval.ms` ms, which is every 3 seconds by default.

so lets say yo have a connetions issue to the borkers for more then 10 seconds you probably got kicked out from the group and the consumer got closed

from [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md) docs about `session.timeout.ms`:

> Client group session and failure detection timeout. The consumer sends periodic heartbeats (heartbeat.interval.ms) to indicate its liveness to the broker. If no hearts are received by the broker for a group member within the session timeout, the broker will remove the consumer from the group and trigger a rebalance. The allowed range is configured with the broker configuration properties group.min.session.timeout.ms and group.max.session.timeout.ms. Also see max.poll.interval.ms.
>   Type: integer